# Total convergence of a function series

Tags: functions, summation, convergence-divergence

Let us consider the following function series:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^x + n^{-x}}.$$

It seems that there is total convergence in $(- \infty, -1-\delta] \cup [1+ \delta, + \infty)$ for $\delta > 0$. Thank-you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica 12.2 does it in such a way:

```
SumConvergence[1/(n^(1 + \[Delta]) + n^(-1 - \[Delta])), n, 
Assumptions -> n >= 1 && \[Delta] > 0, Method -> "IntegralTest"]
```

> `True`

The absolute convergence is obvious since all the terms are positive for each real `x`.
It is its weakness that the commands

```
SumConvergence[1/(n^x + n^-x), n, Assumptions -> x > 0 && n >= 1, Method -> "IntegralTest"]
```

and

```
SumConvergence[1/(n^(1 - \[Delta]) + n^(-1 + \[Delta])), n,Assumptions -> n >= 1 && \[Delta] > 0 && \[Delta] < 1, Method -> "IntegralTest"]
```

return the inputs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the absolute convergence. What about the total convergence?